# Running perl file from jar (placed in same folder)

Tags: java, jar, path

I want to access my perl script (Test.pl) from App.jar which are placed in same folder.
can you explain the path such that i can call perl script from jar.

my directory contains

```
   -Test.pl
   -App.jar
```

And jar structure contains

```
   -Matrix
   -Matrix/Maker.class
   -META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

code :

```
              Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl Test.pl");
              System.out.println(System.getProperty("MatrixMaker"));
              InputStream ir=process.getInputStream();
              BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ir));
              StringBuffer bf=new StringBuffer();

              while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                 bf.append(line);
              }

              jEditorPane1.setText(bf.toString());
```

Comment: where do you start your app from? is it the same directory as jar file or is it a different directory?

Comment: You haven't said if this is Windows or Linux, which would make the details of the answer different. In either case, it is quite likely that the PATH being given to the subprocess does not contain the `perl` executable.  You may need to specify the full path to `perl` or set the PATH correctly.  Also, you must handle subprocess input and output in separate threads or risk deadlocks.  The approach you use here may work one time and fail the next.

Comment: @Mehul The default CMD start directory

Comment: @Jim Its for Windows and both Java and Perl in the %PATH% varible

Comment: Thanks guys! problem was resolved by running app from destination folder....